# C program: How to print a string like this...?

Tags: c

If my input is:   ribbon
The output would be:

```
  rn
 rion  
ribbon
```

or if my input is:  harry

```
  hy
 hary  
harry
```

It should look like a text animation and text should appear one by one (front and the back letter should come in first).

Here is my code, but it does not seem to work since it has a wront output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main () {
    char input[10];
    int front, back;
    int n; //counter

    n = strlen(input);

    printf ("input\n");
    fgets (input, sizeof (input), stdin);

    for (front=0,back=n-1; front<=((n-1)/2)||back>=(((n-1)/2)+1);front++,back--) {
        if (front==0||back&&(n-1)) {
            printf ("%c",input[front]);
            printf ("%c", input[back]);
            front++;
            back--;
            usleep (500000);
        }
        else {
            if (front<=((n-1)/2)||back>=(((n-1)/2)+1)) {
                front++;
                back --;
            }
            else if (front==n) {
                printf ("%c\n", input[front]);
                printf ("%c\n", input[back]);
            }
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `n = strlen(input);` should be done after the `fgets`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time to read the (short!) introductory [tour]. Can you [edit] your question and add what your current output is? See also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [help].

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger and see if you can pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a **specific** problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

There is one major problem: you're trying to determine the length of the input before receiving any input.

so switch the lines like this:

```
printf ("input\n");
fgets (input, sizeof (input), stdin);
n = strlen(input);
```

Then your for-loop ... why so heavy testing, wouldn't

```
for ( front = 0, back = n-1; front < back; ++front, --back)
```

be sufficient?

And at last: the rest of your code.  Please think about it again.  You want to:

- print all characters from the beginning up to and including `front`
- print all characters from back till the end
- print a newline

Your code does nothing about this.  But we're not here to solve your homework ;)

A last hint: there are two different types of stop-condition, and they depend on if your input length is even or odd.  (My suggested test should be ok to catch'em both, tho).